# How to make splash on2. 83

Tags: node-editor, physics, transforms, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

[image]

I'm  new to blender, just trying to understand some basic tools on blender.
So I tried converting a cube
to container that the water will be on and adding a sphere which will drop on the container make splash.
But I got stock onhowvto make the water to splash.

Comment: you'll find a good tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqtuBCpxO0Q

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.